# Why would one need gulp-concat, even though browserify is already being used?

Tags: browserify, gulp-concat

I was of the understanding that Browserify could be used to bundle various JavaScript files into one. However, after looking at some examples on the internet, I found that some people use Browserify and yet they also include gulp-concat.

For example, the [angularjs-gulp-example project](https://github.com/jhades/angularjs-gulp-example/blob/master/gulpfile.js) uses both.

Why? I thought Browserify could do the concatenation as well.

Comment: Maybe they are concatenating non-UMD libraries. Who knows? Who are these people you mention in your question?

Comment: For example, have a look at https://github.com/jhades/angularjs-gulp-example/blob/master/gulpfile.js. It makes use of browserify and gulp-concat.

Answer (score 0):

Browserify is a bundler that creates JavaScript bundles from CommonJS modules. Typically, the bundle will contain all of a project's source files and all of the CommonJS/UMD dependencies. (Also, like Node, Browserify can `require` JSON files, so they could be in the bundle, too.)

If a project has dependencies that are not included using `require` and are instead indended to be used in `<script>` elements - the build process might opt to use a tool like `gulp-concat` to concatenate them to the front of the bundle.

That's likely why `gulp-concat` is used in the project you referenced in your question. It concatenates an Angular template cache that's generated from `.html` files - something Browserify doesn't deal with (unless a transform has been configured).